# Static Block in Product Grid with Load More

Tags: category-listing, magento-2.1.4

We want to add a static block to some of our category pages that will take up the first two spots in the product grid. It would look like this finished:

[image: Static block in category page]

For testing purposes, I've just added a generic li and div tag to the top of the product list.

/app/design/frontend/Theme/default/WeltPixel_CategoryPage/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<?php $iterator = 1; ?>
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
        <li class="item product product-item author-information" style="width: 48.5% !important;">
            <div class="author-container" style="background-color: #f4f4f4; height: 200px;"></div>
        </li>
        <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
```

It renders okish on my local site:

[image: local site with block]

We are using the WeltPixel Pearl Theme with its "AJAX Catalog and Infinite Scroll" so a "Load More" button displays at the bottom of the list.

After I've clicked the "Load More" button, another one of these static blocks displays. We only want the one at the start of the list.

How do I prevent a second static block from displaying?

[image: load more duplicate block]

I also am open to other ways of inserting this content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added code to get the current page and then added it to my if statement.

/app/design/frontend/Theme/default/WeltPixel_CategoryPage/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$currentPage = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;

<ol class="products list items product-items">
    <?php 
    // display the Author Profile as first "product"
    if ($displayAuthor == '1' && $currentPage == 1): ?>
       <li class="item product product-item author-information">
           <div class="author-container">
               <div class="author-info">
                   <img src="<?php echo $category->getAuthorProfileImage(); ?>" />
                    <div class="author-meta">
                        <span class="author-name"><?php echo $category->getAuthorProfileName(); ?></span>
                        <span class="author-title"><?php echo $category->getAuthorProfileTitle(); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p><?php echo $category->getAuthorProfileBio(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```